# Select array entries based on 2D matrix values

Tags: r

I have a simple question that I seem to not be able to wrap my head around. I have a 3D array (an image stack) and I am trying to do a projection onto 2D array (e.g. a maximum intensity projection for an image stack). To do this, I have a matrix of indices which indicate the z-stack to use for each pixel.

For example, I have a 3D array which looks like this:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

And a "selection matrix" which looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
```

The result of this selection should then be

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    6    8
```

i.e. the matrix indicates from which "z-columns" of the array to extract the values.

I know this should be a stupid simple thing but I'm drawing a blank on how to do this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does that works `t(sapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) ar[,,i][cbind(m[i, ], 1:2)]))` (assuming `ar` is your array and `m` is the selection matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use multi-dimensional array indexing via `cbind`:

Here is your data and selection matrix:

```
d <- array(1:8,c(2,2,2))
selec <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2),2,2)
```

First construct a grid of your selection matrix indices:

```
selec.ind <- expand.grid(1:nrow(selec),1:ncol(selec))
```

Then use this with the selection matrix values to access `d`:

```
out <- matrix(d[cbind(selec.ind$Var1,selec.ind$Var2,as.vector(selec))], nrow(selec), ncol(selec))
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]    1    3
##[2,]    6    8
```

Finally, reshape the result back to the size of the selection matrix.

This will work with any size selection matrix and any number of layers in `z`.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for array with 2 third dimensions (`dim=c(...,...,2)`)
The data:

```
ar=array(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),dim = c(2,2,2))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
selec=matrix(c(1,2,1,2),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
```

We use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(selec==1,ar[,,1],ar[,,2])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    6    8
```

Comment: A good idea, but regrettably I have more than 2 layers in the third dimension (11, to be exact)